# React Native android: change app's target API level to at least 31

Tags: android, react-native

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.

> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl377948902.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #145): com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present

Comment: https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/issues/1504

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific module (in this case must be onesignal)
 must be outdated and needs to be updated using:
 yarn add [react-native-onesignal@latestVersion](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-onesignal)

This will update the library version that you have , that might be having outdated androidManifest.XML. This can be verified in android studio, by opening up your androidManifest.XML and clicking on merged manifests to see information about all androidManifests in your project (including those of libraries) [image: Merged Manifests]